# xterm unicode font

Tags: terminal, memory, xterm, terminal-emulator, rxvt

I am having some issues with rxvt-unicode using massive amounts of ram maybe because of using CJK fonts.

On the other hand I cannot get XTerm to display CJK text.

Here's my XTerm Xresources.

```
!------------- XTerm Setup ----------------------!
XTerm.termName: xterm-256color
XTerm.vt100*locale: true
XTerm.vt100*utf8: 2
XTerm.vt100*jumpScroll: true
XTerm.vt100*loginshell: true

XTerm.vt100*cursorBlink:          true
XTerm.vt100*cursorColor:          #657b83
XTerm.vt100*cursorUnderline:      false
XTerm.vt100*saveLines: 999999999999999999999999

!------------- copy-paste ----------------------!
XTerm.vt100*selectToClipboard: true
XTerm.vt100*translations: #override \
        Ctrl Alt <Key>C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
        Ctrl Alt <Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
        Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
        Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font() \n\
        Ctrl <Key> 0: set-vt-font(d)

!------------- fonts ----------------------!
XTerm.vt100*allow_bold: true
XTerm.vt100*faceName: Noto Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 8
XTerm*renderFont: true

!------------- solarized ----------------------!
XTerm.vt100*background: #002b36
XTerm.vt100*foreground: #657b83
XTerm.vt100*fadeColor: #002b36
XTerm.vt100*pointerColorBackground: #586e75
XTerm.vt100*pointerColorForeground: #93a1a1

!! black dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color0: #073642
XTerm.vt100*color8: #002b36

!! red dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color1: #dc322f
XTerm.vt100*color9: #cb4b16

!! green dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color2: #859900
XTerm.vt100*color10: #586e75

!! yellow dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color3: #b58900
XTerm.vt100*color11: #657b83

!! blue dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color4: #268bd2
XTerm.vt100*color12: #839496

!! magenta dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color5: #d33682
XTerm.vt100*color13: #6c71c4

!! cyan dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color6: #2aa198
XTerm.vt100*color14: #93a1a1

!! white dark/light
XTerm.vt100*color7: #eee8d5
XTerm.vt100*color15: #fdf6e3

!!! white color for BOLD TEXT
!!! green color for ITALICS TEXT
XTerm.vt100*colorBD: white
XTerm.vt100*colorIT: green

! mouse curson settings
XTerm.vt100*theme: whiteglass
XTerm.vt100*size: 32
```

my RXvt config is pretty similar:

```
xft.dpi:                    220
xft.antialias:              false
xft.rgba:                   rgb
xft.hinting:                true
xft.hintstyle:              hintslight

! mouse curson settings
xcursor.theme: whiteglass
xcursor.size: 32
```

urxvt setup

```
urxvt.termname:             rxvt-unicode-256color
urxvt.depth:                32
urxvt.geometry:             90x30
urxvt.transparent:          false
urxvt.fading:               0
urxvt.loginshell:           true
urxvt.savelines:            100000000
urxvt.internalborder:       3
urxvt.linespace:            0

! ibus
urxvt.inputmethod: ibus
urxvt.preedittype: overthespot

! fonts
urxvt.allow_bold:           true
urxvt*font: xft:fira mono-regular:pixelsize=24
urxvt*boldfont: xft:fira mono-bold:pixelsize=28


! fix font space
urxvt*letterspace: -1

! scrollbar
urxvt.scrollstyle:          rxvt
urxvt.scrollbar:            false

! perl extensions
urxvt.perl-ext-common:      default,matcher
urxvt.matcher.button:       1
urxvt.urllauncher:          firefox

! cursor
urxvt.cursorblink:          true
urxvt.cursorcolor:          #657b83
urxvt.cursorunderline:      false

! pointer
urxvt.pointerblank:         true

!!source http://github.com/altercation/solarized

urxvt.background: #002b36
urxvt.foreground: #657b83
urxvt.fadecolor: #002b36
urxvt.pointercolorbackground: #586e75
urxvt.pointercolorforeground: #93a1a1

!! black dark/light
urxvt.color0: #073642
urxvt.color8: #002b36

!! red dark/light
urxvt.color1: #dc322f
urxvt.color9: #cb4b16

!! green dark/light
urxvt.color2: #859900
urxvt.color10: #586e75

!! yellow dark/light
urxvt.color3: #b58900
urxvt.color11: #657b83

!! blue dark/light
urxvt.color4: #268bd2
urxvt.color12: #839496

!! magenta dark/light
urxvt.color5: #d33682
urxvt.color13: #6c71c4

!! cyan dark/light
urxvt.color6: #2aa198
urxvt.color14: #93a1a1

!! white dark/light
urxvt.color7: #eee8d5
urxvt.color15: #fdf6e3

urxvt.colorbd: white
urxvt.colorit: green
```

My X startup script runs these commands.

```
setenv XIM ibus
setenv GTK_IM_MODULE ibus
setenv QT_IM_MODULE ibus
setenv XMODIFIERS @im=ibus
setenv XIM_PROGRAM ibus-daemon
setenv XIM_ARGS "--daemonize --replace --xim"

ibus-daemon --daemonize --replace --xim & 
ibus engine chewing &
```

With that XTerm fails to type any unicode font, no CJK input or output, copy and paste shows empty spaces.

RXVT-Unicode works but uses gobs of ram
10719 user        1  20    0 22697M   253M select  3   0:01   0.47%

```
urxvt
 8197 user        1  20    0 22693M   250M select  7   0:01   0.00% urxvt
10184 user        1  20    0 11411M   252M select  5   0:01   0.00% urxvt
 8123 user        1  20    0 11402M   249M select  5   0:01   0.00% urxvt
 8090 user        1  20    0 11402M   249M select  1   0:26   0.00% urxvt
10706 user        1  20    0 11402M   249M select  6   0:00   0.00% urxvt
 8257 user        1  20    0 11401M   249M select  2   0:28   0.05% urxvt
```

Any ideas to;
Fix the high ram usage on RXvt-unicode
Get XTerm to display Unicode
Other lightweight terminal emulators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitation is with these settings:

```
XTerm.vt100*faceName: Noto Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 8
XTerm*renderFont: true
```

xterm supports a single font (no font-sets, which are merged at runtime).  None of the TrueType fonts covers enough of CJK to be interesting.  The bitmap fonts used in xterm's default resource settings are good enough for most uses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can I ask what would be a sane replacement that can display unicode CJK fonts and is lightweight? I don't need anything special like tabbed browsing [I use i3-wm]. I would like something light on RAM but supports unicode font sets. Any ideas?